# Move or delete when file open

Tags: c#

Is it possible to move/delete a file inside using a statement like this:

```
using (
    var fileStream = new FileStream(
        @"someShare\someFile.txt",
        FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read,
        FileShare.None,
        512,
        FileOptions.None))
{
    // Here how to remove that file and then release stream? 
}
```

What I want to achieve is to copy the file to the archive after my process finishes processing, but before releasing the stream.

If I move the file after using statement it is possible that some other instance of my code will lock the file.

`FileOptions.DeleteOnClose` is not an option because I do not want to remove the file if there will be any exception inside using statement

Comment: it depends on if someone has a lock on the file.

Comment: `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose` may or may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: @JeroenMostert please put this an answer, this is what I was looking for. Some people thought that I used 'using' only to delete file...

Comment: Are you OK with other processes possibly deleting the file (but no other operation) while you are using the stream? If so, then `FileShare.Delete` with an optional `File.Delete` in a `finally` will get you what you want. If you're not OK with that, then I see no way of doing what you want on one single file, unless using something like transactional NTFS (which is deprecated). There will be inevitably be a small gap between you being done with the file and deleting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a using block, but you have to specifiy you **want to** delete it.

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Delete, 4096, true))
{
    stream.Flush();
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileoptions) "indicates that a file is automatically deleted when it is no longer in use" So you can do:

```
using (
    var fileStream = new FileStream(
        @"someShare\someFile.txt",
        FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read,
        FileShare.None,
        512,
        FileOptions.DeleteOnClose
    )
) {
    // do something nice with the stream
}
```

Note that if other processes (or even your own) have already opened the file elsewhere, it will remain open until the last handle to it is closed. It will not necessarily be deleted immediately after you're done with it (but with `FileShare.None`, you can be reasonably sure you *are* the only one using it, otherwise the stream would not have opened).

Comment: this is almost what I was looking, but the problem with it is that If my 'something nice with the stream' throws an exception then I really do not want to delete that file.

Comment: @kosnkov: In that case you definitely *can't* use `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose` (not on its own, in any case), because that's a death sentence for the stream once opened (you can't "skip" cleanup of the `FileStream`). You should change your question to include that, because the answer would be very different. (Indeed, I can't immediately think of a way to do it!)

Answer (score -3):

You don't need a `using` block.  Just use `System.IO.File.Delete`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx